# Avoiding copypasting subqueries twice inside the SELECT portion of the MySQL query

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.*,
                           ( 3959 * Acos(Cos(Radians((SELECT latitude
                                                      FROM   wp_product_city
                                                      WHERE
                                             city_slug = 'toronto'))) * Cos(
                                         Radians(
                                         tbl_product_location.latitude)) * Cos(
                                         Radians(
                                         tbl_product_location.longitude)
                                             - Radians((SELECT longitude
                                             FROM   wp_product_city
                                             WHERE
                                             city_slug = 'toronto')
                                                 )) +
                                         Sin(
                                                       Radians((SELECT latitude
                                                                FROM
                                                       wp_product_city
                                                                WHERE
                                                       city_slug = 'toronto')))
                                         * Sin(
                                         Radians
                                         (
                                         tbl_product_location.latitude))) ) AS
                           distance,
                           wp.product_location
FROM   wp_posts
       INNER JOIN wp_product wp
               ON wp.post_id = wp_posts.id
       INNER JOIN wp_product_product_location tbl_product_location
               ON tbl_product_location.product_location = wp.product_location
WHERE  1 = 1
       AND ( wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' )
ORDER  BY distance ASC
```

So I have this query, the problem is that I am copy pasting a subquery twice, and I can't find another way to do this. I tried joining the table, but since the select elements are done before the joins, it doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to avoid copy-pasting the subquery twice?

```
SELECT latitude
FROM   wp_product_city
WHERE  city_slug = 'toronto'
```

This is the one I am copy-pasting twice.

Answer (score 0):

Use a CTE (Common Table Expression).

For example:

```
with lat as (
  SELECT latitude, longitude
  FROM   wp_product_city
  WHERE  city_slug = 'toronto' 
)
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.*,
  ( 3959 * Acos(Cos(Radians((SELECT latitude from lat))) * Cos( ...
  ... (SELECT longitude FROM lat)
  ... (SELECT latitude FROM lat)
```

This way all the complex or repetitive logic gets typed only once at the beginning of the query.

Comment: Hmm, is there a way to do this on Wordpress? $clauses['fields'] $clauses['joins'], I need to append the query inside these arrays and I think I am only limited to one query not two.

Comment: @saro That's a single query.